# How to format a ReturnString Array from a webService

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, web-services

I get a returnString from a WebService in iOS:

```
[
{"datum":"2013-07-24
09:38:43","nummer":"1017348010239480212208","anmerkung":"Elektronische
Auftragsdaten wurden vom Versender
\u00fcbermittelt"},{"datum":"2013-07-24
09:38:44","nummer":"1017348010239480212208","anmerkung":"Sendung in
Verteilung"},{"datum":"2013-07-24
09:38:44","nummer":"1017348010239480212208","anmerkung":"Sendung in
Verteilung"},{"datum":"2013-07-24
09:38:44","nummer":"1017348010239480212208","anmerkung":"Sendung in
Zustellung"},{"datum":"2013-07-24
09:26:06","nummer":"1017348010239480212208","anmerkung":"Empf\u00e4nger
nicht angetroffen - benachrichtigt"},{"datum":"2013-07-19
06:24:42","nummer":"1017348010239480212208","anmerkung":"Sendung in
Post-Empfangsbox eingelangt"}
]
```

the Objective C Code works fine:

```
#import "SBJson.h"

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.textfeld.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", returnString];
```

I try to format the Response with NSMutableArray or NSArray and JSONValue but without success :

```
NSMutableArray *meinErgebnis = [responseString JSONValue];

NSLog(@"%@",[[meinErgebnis objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1]);
```

**How to format the returnCode like that?**

```
Nummer: 1017348010239480212208
Anmerkung: Sendung in Verteilung

Nummer: 1017348010239480212208
Anmerkung: Sendung in Post-Empfangsbox
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code for get all the values of **nummer** and **anmerkung** from your mutable array.

```
NSMutableArray *meinErgebnis = [responseString JSONValue];

for(int i = 0; i < meinErgebnis.count; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[[meinErgebnis objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nummer"]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[[meinErgebnis objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"anmerkung"]);
}
```

Comment: @ArunThiru : fast-enumeration? how?

Comment: @LithuT.V For each loop is nothing but fast-enumeration

Comment: Can you elaborate? I dont get what you are trying to say

Comment: @LithuT.V refer vish answer

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain Data with following method,

```
 id Data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:fetchedData options:kNilOptions   error:&error];
```

Then you can loop the data accordingly. For your example,

```
for(id object in Data)
{
   NSLog(@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"nummer"]);
   NSLog(@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"anmerkung"]);
}
```

The loop used above is of fast Enumeration type. Hope this helps.